# MySQL execute queries with multiple time intervals

Tags: mysql

I have the following query

```
SELECT channel_type, 
       AVG(delay_in_seconds) 
FROM   a_table 
WHERE  started_at BETWEEN '2014-10-17 00:00:00' AND '2014-10-17 23:59:59' 
GROUP  BY channel_type;
```

Currently if i wanted to run this query on a one week interval for the past 10 weeks i would need to run 10 separate queries and manually change the intervals. what would be a more elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think SQL has the flexibility you're looking for in this situation (although I may be wrong). I needed to a similar thing a while ago and simply had to run the query over and over. If you are concerned about improvement you could turn your query a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Consider placing the query in a scripting language and outputting the results to a report file. Python's MySqlDb library is very easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something that you can run everyday:

```
SELECT channel_type, AVG(delay_in_seconds) 
FROM   a_table 
WHERE  started_at BETWEEN CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' 00:00:00') AND CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' 23:59:59')
GROUP  BY channel_type;
```

If you need a summary per week:

```
SELECT channel_type, WEEK(started_at) AS week, AVG(delay_in_seconds) 
FROM   a_table
GROUP  BY channel_type, week;
```

If you need  a summary per day:

```
SELECT channel_type, DATE(started_at) AS dt, AVG(delay_in_seconds) 
FROM   a_table
GROUP  BY channel_type, dt;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

```
 SELECT channel_type,AVG(delay_in_seconds),weeknum
 FROM   (
         SELECT channel_type, delay_in_seconds,WEEK(started_at) as weeknum
         FROM a_table 
         )   
 GROUP  BY channel_type, weeknum;
```

The only problem is that you get results for all weeks. You can add a clause where in the inner query after you calculate the week numbers. for example

where week num >25 or between ect